# how to send formData to php with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, file, upload

I am trying to generate multiple form that will provide a system to upload multiple files. So far code is

```
<?php 
    ...
foreach($all_cat as $cat)
{
?>
<form method="post" class="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
<i class="cloud-upload"></i> Add Files
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
<input type="submit" value ="uplaod" size="60">
</form>
...
<?php
...
```

jquery

```
$(".uploadform").on('submit',(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('input[type=file]').val()=="")
     {
         alert("no file is selected");
         return false;
     }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "form_process.php", 
            type: "POST",             
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false, 
            processData:false, 
            success: function(result)
                    {
                        alert(result);
                    }
        })//ajax
    }//else
}));//onsubmit
```

But it seems that form_process.php file is not getting data form jquery. alert producing long mark-up of table, and somewhere in that it says file name can not be empty.

form_process.php

```
if(isset($_FILES['files']))
{
  foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key3)
  {
    $exif = exif_imagetype($key3);
    echo "file type is ".$exif."<br/>";
  }
```

How do I access those selected files upload and other data of the form? I have been trying for hours, anybody can help me,please ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try appending them instead of using 'this'.